# Python Docker ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Tags: python, docker

I am new to the docker world, and i need to create an docker image for the front-end programmers in my team.

this is how my dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /backend

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY config.py ./

COPY ./api ./api

CMD [ "python", "./api/service/server.py" ]
```

And this is how the structure looks like,
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUlrr.png)

When I try to run my docker image, the terminal gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./api/service/server.py", line 1, in <module>
    import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

And in server.py I wrote `import config`

Comment: You seem to have put a link to an image file instead of the contents of your Dockerfile.  Can you edit the question to delete the image link, and instead include the text of the Dockerfile (and anything else required for a [mcve]) directly in the question?

Comment: i have replaced the image with the code @DavidMaze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem, it seems like i needed to use an ENV in my dockerfile

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/backend"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely going by the images (as it's not reproducible) I'd say you copy `requirements.txt` twice in your file, but you **don't** copy `config.py` at all. Since according to your structure it's not under `.api` it won't be copied at all and therefor most likely is missing, hence the error.

Comment: i have replaced the second one with `COPY config.py ./` , but it did not change the outcome

Comment: So it's likely code-based then. When importing in python the path matters. The config file's location in the container therefor also matter. Please check that (maybe you can copy the config under the same directory as the server.py)? Did it work locally before putting this in a container?